# How to use Text.StaticLayout in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am developing a custom view extending View in android that contains a long text to be drawn. I would like to marquee the text. I am not able to understand how to use StaticLayout or BoringLayout in android to Marquee.

Comment: Please include specifics about what you've tried and what you don't understand.

Comment: new StaticLayout(name,0, name.length(),namePaint, 230, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0F, 0.0F, true,TruncateAt.MARQUEE,0);I am not able to control the position of the layout and also the number of lines in the layout